# emulator aosp wsl2 segmentation fault on launch

Tags: wsl2, emulator, android-x86

Facing an issue with wsl2 when starting aosp emulator. It was working before and now after some updates it does not work.

I'm on WSL2 with

```
uname -a : 5.15.57.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
```

I'm starting emulator with command line :

```
emulator -writable-system -allow-host-audio
```

[image: wsl 2 crash dmesg]

wsl --status

[image: wsl --status]

Any help would be welcome :)

Thanks for your help

Comment: What does "Does Not Work" mean ?  And it's better to copy/paste the text rather than using images.

Answer (score 1):

*Short answer:*

Try downgrading WSL and or the kernel.  If that works, please file a new [issue on the WSL2 Github repo](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues).  Include the information on your Windows build as well as `wsl --status` results.

*More detail:*

> now after some updates it does not work.

> `5.15.57.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2`

You don't mention your Windows version in your question, but that would indicate that you are probably using a Windows 11 *Insider* build.  Last week was the first time in a long while that the WSL team:

- Updated the Linux kernel (from 5.10.102.1 to [5.15.57.1](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel/releases/tag/linux-msft-wsl-5.15.57.1))
- Pushed a WSL "Pre-release" ([0.65.1](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/discussions/8678)) to Insiders.  I don't think they've done that since Windows 10.  Typically all releases have been considered "Preview" since they moved to the Microsoft Store delivery model.  The "pre-release", to me, indicates some additional concern that the team had that it might need additional testing on Insider builds before being made available to Preview opt-in via the Store.

And there was at least one serious regression ([issue 8679](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8679), but it doesn't *appear* to be related to the issue you are seeing.  And regardless, from reading that issue, you should have received the subsequent (still pre-release) update that fixes that particular issue.

Since the emulator issue started after an upgrade, though, I would definitely try rolling back to the previous release(s).

Start with the WSL package itself:

- Download the [0.64.0 release](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases/tag/0.64.0) package from the repo
- Exit WSL and `wsl --shutdown`
- From an *administrative* PowerShell:

  ```
  Add-AppxPackage -Path .\Microsoft.WSL_0.64.0.0_x64_ARM64.msixbundle -ForceUpdateFromAnyVersion -ForceApplicationShutdown
  ```
- Confirm installation via `wsl --status`.
- Start WSL and try again.

If it is still not fixed, you may need to try rolling back the kernel release separately.

- Download the GA kernel (5.10.102.1) from the link in the [Manual Installation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package) steps.
- Create a directory for the kernel (something like `C:\WSL\kernel\5.10.102.1`).
- From a CMD shell:

  ```
  cd <download_directory>

  msiexec /a wsl_update_x64.msi TARGETDIR=C:\WSL
  ```
- You should now have `C:\WSL\System32\lxss\tools\kernel`.  Move this to the `C:\WSL\kernel\5.10.102.1` directory.
- Create or edit `%userprofile%\.wslconfig` (that's your Windows user profile, not WSL):

  ```
  [wsl2]
  kernel = C:\\WSL\\kernel\\5.10.102.1\\kernel
  ```
- `wsl --shutdown`
- Restart and check `uname -a`.

Comment: Hello thanks for your detailled answer, I just followed your instructions and result is the same. check my edited answer

Comment: @X6Entrepreneur Ugh - Sorry that didn't work.  Well, could be something else in the Insider update, but it could be unrelated, of course.  Is there a website or something where I can read through the AOSP emulator installation instructions?  If it's not too time consuming, I can test it out on my installation.  What distribution are you using?  Apologies if it's in the question, but I'm not seeing it at first glance.  Thanks!

Comment: @X6Entrepreneur Nevermind - I see the instructions in your [Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8700).  I'll see if I can give it a shot.  You should mention in your Github issue that you've also tried it on 5.10.102.1 -- Otherwise the first assumption of the Microsoft team is probably going to be the same as mine - A regression in 5.15.57.1, which we now know it's not.

Comment: I updated the Github issue too. Thanks a lot if you can try on your side and let me know if it occurs. :)